# Use Control.Monad.Trans.Except instead - how to turn off this warning in ghc?

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to turn off warning in ghc compiler ?

```
Deprecated: "Use Control.Monad.Trans.Except instead"
```

Comment: Use `Control.Monad.Trans.Except`. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do with

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-warnings-deprecations -#}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-deprecated-flags -#}
```

But I would **not** recommend that - better change your import to importing the mentioned package.